# Html5 submit form button-send input to file?

Tags: forms, submit, user-input, data-storage, form-submit

I have a multi-page website, I'm still new to programming but have learned quite a bit of HTML and CSS. My question is:

How can I have my submit form button take a users input-data, and send it to a .txt file on my computer while offline?

This is simply so I can test my form and be sure that it can SEND the input data. This form is a model application and includes text boxes, radio buttons, select lists, passwords, emails etc...

And for the moment I do not need salt-hashing or any security, simply for off-line form testing, thanks!

Edit: I do have a submit button properly set in, but it does not send the input data anywhere

Answer (score 2):

If you are offline, then there is no way for your computer to receive data.

However, if your web site is on a web server out on the Internet, the data can be saved to a text file on the server, for access to later.

The form itself needs an action tag, which tells the form where the data should be sent for processing. It has a few important tags within it as well:

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.yoursite.com/script-to-process-submission.php">
    One: <input type='text' name='inputbox1'/>
    Two: <input type='text' name='inputbox2'/>
</form>
```

You place all your input boxes within the form tags. The method can be "get" or "post" which is the way in which the data is sent. A get method means that all the responses from the input boxes are sent in the url, separated by ampersands, like this:

```
http://www.yoursite.com/script-to-process-submission.php?inputbox1=what+the+user+entered&inputbox2=also+what+the+user+entered
```

The issue here is that a long form may not have all data submitted-- often servers limit the length of input that can be sent this way. A longer form is better with the "post" method.

Once the form is submitted, and the data has been sent to the server, you need a script set up in a server-side language like Perl or PHP. Here is an example in PHP:

```
<?php
$response = "";
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $response .= $key . " -> " . $value . "\n";
}
// now save to disk in a file called saved_response.txt
// the FILE_APPEND adds the form responses to the text file, and the LOCK_EX locks the file first
file_put_contents('saved_response.txt',$response,FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
exit;
```

If you preferred the get method, change $_POST above to $_GET.

IMPORTANT NOTE: there is no cleaning involved in the above code, and a malicious user could send bad data to your server, and cause harm. You should consider some sort of cleaning of the text which is submitted, such as:

```
$clean_value = preg_replace("/[^ 0-9a-zA-Z]/", "_", $value);
```

You would put this right before the $response.= line above. It's role is to keep only numbers, and lowercase/uppercase letters.

Save this php code as a plain text file 'script-to-process-submission.php', and try your form.